# CSS Grid and SVG on Chrome

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I build a button with the background is an SVG. I use CSS Grid to locate the text and the background with this code:

StyledButton

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 40px 1fr 40px;
grid-template-rows: 16px 1fr 16px;
place-items: center;
```

SVG layer

```
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1/-1;
```

Text layer

```
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1/-1;
```

But in Chrome the text cannot overlay the svg layer, even though in Firefox it's perfectly OK with this, like in the picture below. Does anyone have any solution?

[image]

// Update my messy workable code

The SVG component:

```
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import PropType from "prop-types"

const SuperEllipse = ({ width, height, radius, className }) => {
  const horizontalLine = width - radius
  const verticalLine = height - radius

  return (
    <SVGWrapper className={className}>
      <StyledSVG
        version="1.1"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        x="0px"
        y="0px"
        width={width}
        height={height}
        // viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`}
        enableBackground={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`}
        xmlSpace="preserve"
      >
        <path
          fill="#EDEB"
          stroke="none"
          d={`
        M 0,${radius}
        C 0,0 0,0 ${radius},0
        L ${horizontalLine},0                                    
        C ${width},0 ${width},0 ${width},${radius}
        L ${width},${verticalLine}
        C ${width},${height} ${width},${height} ${horizontalLine},${height}
        L ${radius},${height}
        C 0,${height} 0,${height} 0,${verticalLine}
        L 0,${radius} 
        `}
        />
      </StyledSVG>
    </SVGWrapper>
  )
}

SuperEllipse.propTypes = {
  width: PropType.number,
  height: PropType.number,
  radius: PropType.number,
}

SuperEllipse.defaultProps = {
  width: 240,
  height: 24,
  radius: 0,
}

const StyledSVG = styled.svg`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1/-1;
`

const SVGWrapper = styled.div``

export default SuperEllipse
```

The Button.js:

```
import React, { useRef, useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

import StyleUtils from "../../utils/style-utils"
import SuperEllipse from "./SuperEllipse"

const handleSize = size => {
  let buttonValues = {}
  if (size === "large") {
    buttonValues = {
      height: StyleUtils.pxToRem(56),
      fontSize: StyleUtils.pxToRem(20),
      horizontalPadding: StyleUtils.pxToRem(90),
      borderRadius: StyleUtils.pxToRem(14),
    }
  } else if (size === "medium") {
    buttonValues = {
      height: StyleUtils.pxToRem(32),
      fontSize: StyleUtils.pxToRem(12),
      horizontalPadding: StyleUtils.pxToRem(16),
      borderRadius: StyleUtils.pxToRem(5),
    }
  } else if (size === "small") {
    buttonValues = {
      height: StyleUtils.pxToRem(24),
      fontSize: StyleUtils.pxToRem(10),
      horizontalPadding: StyleUtils.pxToRem(12),
      borderRadius: StyleUtils.pxToRem(4),
    }
  }
  return buttonValues
}

const Button = ({ children, size, onClick }) => {
  const targetRef = useRef()
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 })

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (targetRef.current) {
      setDimensions({
        width: targetRef.current.offsetWidth,
        height: targetRef.current.offsetHeight,
      })
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      <StyledButton ref={targetRef} size={size} onClick={onClick}>
        <ChildrenWrapper>{children}</ChildrenWrapper>
        <Background
          width={dimensions.width}
          height={dimensions.height}
          radius={24}
        />
      </StyledButton>
    </div>
  )
}

Button.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  size: PropTypes.string,
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

Button.defaultProps = {
  size: "large",
}

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  height: ${props => handleSize(props.size).height}rem;
  font-size: ${props => handleSize(props.size).fontSize}rem;
  padding: 0px !important;
  background: blue;
  outline: 0;
  width: 400px;
  border: 0;
  /* padding: 0 ${props => handleSize(props.size).horizontalPadding}rem; */
  /* background-image: radial-gradient(
    50% 143%,
    #e3ecf6 50%,
    #e3ecf6 100%,
    #e3ecf6 100%
  ); */

  /* box-shadow: 0 20px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04),
    0 1px 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 1px 2px 9px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02),
    1px 4px 10px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03), 2px 5px 10px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03),
    2px 7px 11px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03), 3px 8px 11px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02),
    4px 10px 12px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01); */
  /* border: 1px solid; */
  border-image: linear-gradient(178deg, #e8f4fe 7%, rgba(233, 240, 246, 0) 100%)
    1;

  border-radius: ${props => handleSize(props.size).borderRadius}rem;
  color: white;

  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  & :hover {
    border-color: var(--color-active);
    color: var(--color-active);
  }
  outline: none;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40px 1fr 40px;
  grid-template-rows: 16px 1fr 16px;
  place-items: center;
`

const Background = styled(SuperEllipse)`
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1/-1;
`

const ChildrenWrapper = styled.div`
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1/-1;
`

export default Button
```

The page:

```
import React from "react"
import Button from "../components/atom/Button"

const draft = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button>What the hell</Button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default draft
```

Comment: pls share workable code. iwll check and let you know

Comment: @Ranjithv I've updated my messy code